# Header of similar question list too small

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When opening the *Similar Questions* list, for instance this one https://stackoverflow.com/search/next-answer?answerid=29760922

the header is too small for the long question text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in the most recent build.